# Print all UTF-16 Letters to console (Java)

Tags: java, utf-16

I have actually a very simple code. I just try to print out all UTF-16 signs. It works particular but most of the signs this program prints are not readable.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 65535; i++) {
        try {
            System.out.println(new String(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(i).array(), "UTF-16"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Charset.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Why is that and how can i please fix it?

Thank you

Comment: did u fix it? please post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not all 16 bit integers are valid Unicode codepoints.  Also, for the valid codepoints, your display device must have a full set of fonts, which is rarely the case.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want a `short` rather than an `int`. I'd say you want to allocate 2 bytes rather than 4, and use `putShort()`.

That said, [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) is actually variable-length, so it won't be as simple as just printing every code point. Check the article for details. It also depends on whether whatever font you're using has the right glyphs.